# Datechooser for SQL query

Tags: java, sql

I have two tables made in access.  One table (Owner) contains: `ownerID`, name which owner has.  Second table (Cars) contains: `CarId`, `carname`, `year`, `ownerID` they has relations between `carid`

In my java program I get from first table `OwnerName` and put them all into `comboBox1`

```
String sql="SELECT * FROM Owner ;";
    ResultSet dane = zadanie.executeQuery(sql);
     while(dane.next()) {
         String  OwnerId = dane.getString("OwnerID");
         String OwnerName = dane.getString("OwnerName");
         if (OwnerId != null) {OwnerId = OwnerId.trim();}
         if (OwnerName != null) {OwnerName = OwnerName.trim();}
         comboBox.addItem(OwnerId);
         comboBox_1.addItem(OwnerName);
     }
```

When I choose owner I want to have in `combobox2` only these cars that have this owner.

Can someone suggest a solution?

I don't know exactly how to write the SQL statement to get that.

Comment: What does this have to do with "datechooser"?

Comment: Please give us at least a database layout. What is car table called like and what columns does it have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select tablename.carname from tablename where ownerID=SelectedOwnerID
```

To get selected owner id you can, for example, create a map `Map<Integer,Integer>` and store pairs ComboboxItemNumber -> OwnerId

Comment: can you give more information how to make map and get SelectedOwnerID
?

Comment: [Here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/GetselectedItemfromJComboBox.htm) is described how to get selected item of combobox. When you will have index (or name) of owner you shall pass it into your query. To create map you can do following: <br> Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<string,Integer>(); // if you will map ownerName->ownerId. When you iterating through result set, do the following: map.put(OwnerName,OwnerId);<br> After it you will be able to get ownerId by selected owner name with the following map's method: int ownerId = map.get(selectedOwnerName);

Comment: btw, i have to make string:
String sql2="select tablename.carname from tablename where ownerID=SelectedOwnerID;"; and do as i done i my upper example
or do in another way

Comment: you have to do both. Firstly - fill two comboboxes as you already done. Next, when user click on any line of first two comboboxes you have to invoke new method and fill third combobox with cars of selected owner (if i'v understood you). And your second sql query will be   select Cars.carname from Cars where ownerID=SelectedOwnerID

Comment: String SelectedCarID=carmap.get(comboBox_2.getSelectedItem());


   String sql="select Owner.ownername from Owner where carID=SelectedcarID"; what wrong with this?

Comment: no it doesnt understand carID=SelectedcarID this statement
i thnk ve set sql as a string and it try to find SelectedcarID in my table

Comment: if you use jdbc, you have to use PreparedStatement object and pass your parameter to sql query. You have to read about common jdbc usages.